# Linear regression using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a novice and need help processing billions of records to find the non-sequence in the data set. 
this use case needs to calculate r2 value for each user level, so can't use test/train datasets.

I am Using from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

My data set is like this in the table  :

```
User_id  type rank_by_type sequence 
1        A      1           1
1        A      2           7
1        B      1           5
1        B      2           6
```

So i need to find the r2 score to determine if the sequence is not in order, i.e in the above example 5,6 is in seq but 1,7 are not in seq. User_id and Type makes a unique record.

Please suggest how can i use the logic to calculate r2 and also what's the best way to process huge dataset using spark.ml

Comment: Where is the user level in your dataset?

Comment: Can you have more than two rows with same user_id and type? Is rank_by_type always increasing by one and starting at one?

Comment: User level is combo of User_id and Type

Comment: Yes, user_id and type can be any number of records, I am setting rank based on time(its increment of 1 and starting from 1 ) so i know the rank for the sequences,  need to flag the no sequences based on r2.

Comment: That looks like a case for windowed aggregation using `rank_dense` standard function.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this and it should work fine.

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

# Load training data
training = spark.read.format("libsvm")\
    .load("data/mllib/sample_linear_regression_data.txt")

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)

# Fit the model
lrModel = lr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercept for linear regression
print("Coefficients: %s" % str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: %s" % str(lrModel.intercept))

# Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
print("numIterations: %d" % trainingSummary.totalIterations)
print("objectiveHistory: %s" % str(trainingSummary.objectiveHistory))
trainingSummary.residuals.show()
print("RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
print("r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)
```

Reference:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression

Comment: This comment is just the docs example, which already has a `features` and `labels` column.